# Selected text track on HTMLMediaElement?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I have a `video` tag that contains several `track`s. How do I get the one that's currently loaded/selected by the user?

I've checked the W3C and Mozilla documentation pages, it's possible to enumerate the texttracks, but I don't see how to determine which one is active/selected.

Comment: Have you checked `currentSrc` property? As a experience you should create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextTrack.mode might suffice: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextTrack/mode.